# Make a cell color itself based on RGB value in three cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have no idea why this code doesn't work.

```
Function colorme(Red As Integer, Green As Integer, Blue As Integer)
    Application.Caller.Interior.color = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
```

I want to make it work in spreadsheet like:

```
__red__|_green_|_blue__|_color_|_
____50_|_____0_|____60_|#purple|_
```

But the #purple is actually purple, using colorme(A2,B2,C2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user-defined function cannot change any properties of a cell except the value of the cell that contains the formula.  You could write a subroutine to change the colors of the cells, but unless I'm mistaken, the way you're trying isn't possible.

Comment: Ok, I found out that you are right, it's impossible with functions. I have no idea why. Thank you.